# Modify existing GWT application

Tags: java, gwt

I have a WAR file of some GWT application. No source project.
I need to do some modifications in this application like adding new buttons to the actionbar etc.

I've unrared WAR file and inside WEB-INF/classes there are .classes and .java files as well.
So the source code of Java classes is available.
JavaScript files under deferredjs folder are obfuscated.

Sadly I'm not a GWT expert.
So the question is: is it possible to modify existing GWT application having WAR with .java files?
And how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Not trivially. It's about the same as hand-editing a binary executable.

Comment: Among the `.java` files you find in the WAR, are there any that `import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint`?

Comment: 4 classes have EntryPoint. Log.java, TestDisclosurePanel.java, PalettePanel.java, EntryPointImpl.java. Is there some use of those files?

Comment: If it is client-side code, then no, because that logic has been cross-compiled into Javascript. However if it's server-side logic, it's possible. My co-worker has successfully repackaged class files in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Somewhat longer answer: As chrylis mentioned in the comments, the JavaScript produced by the GWT compiler resembles binary code. It is highly optimized an obfuscated. No chance to decompile and very unlikely to modify by hand.

Comment: I wasn't going to decompile javascripts, but to use .java files I can extract from WAR. Is there something that wouldn't let me rebuild the modified application from .java files?

Comment: I usually don't include the client-side .class files in the WAR. Because the files are unnecessary and for security reasons, I don't want anybody to decompile them ;-) But if you are lucky and the developer of your app did include the files... Yeah it might work.